# Different approaches to get all webs titles

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jsom, sub-site

**Context : SharePoint Online.**

**Scenario :** We have more than 3000 sub-sites in site collection. Currently we have developed one web-part which contains one text-box. In which whenever user will start typing Autocomplete will show title of all matching sub-sites.

**What we did is :** On page load, we are looping through all sub-sites, retrieving title then storing it in array and finally binding this array to Jquery UI Autocomplete. Our web-part is working fine.

**Problem :**
 Since there are 3000 sub-sites, It taking almost **30 seconds** on page load to bind all sub-site's titles. So we want to reduce this time.

So Is there any faster approach to get titles of all sub-sites.

Comment: How are you retrieving the sub site names? Are you looping through each subsite to get child or using search(=>will give you better performance)?

Comment: Thank Unnie for reply. Currently i am looping through each subsite and getting their title. I want all subsites titles in array on page load. So how can we achieve this using 'Search'. Can you please provide some code.